# How to not reveal that you are using PHP?

Tags: web-application, webserver, disclosure

I'm bulding a website but some webtools and browser plugins allows anyone to get information on which technologies the website has been built. Is there any Alternative to not reveal that we are working on server that process php ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you link some of these webtools and browser plugins?

Comment: @liori https://github.com/ElbertF/Wappalyzer

Answer (score 23):

Don't provide any information to anyone unless its absolutely necessary.

You should set `expose_php=off` in your PHP.ini.  This tells PHP not to expose the "x-powered-by" HTTP header as well as the strange quarks that can be used to identify it.  You should also set `display_errors=Off` which could be used to identify PHP as well as error-based vulnerabilities like SQL Injection.  These two configurations should be used on all production systems. You can go a step further and remove or change the .php extension with mod_rewrite.

This is along the same lines as "banner information disclosure",  which is revealing version information via service banners.  You should be able to configure your HTTPD to suppress this information. In an Apache production environment set `ServerTokens ProductOnly` (thanks tftd).  But this will just remove the version number, if you want to remove the word "apache"  you have to use mod_security.

You could also lie >:).  You can use mod_header to set any header,  including a fake `x-powered-by`, and just adopt .aspx file extensions using mod_rewrite.

Comment: In addition to what you said, some variables like PHPSESSID should also be renamed. Using a URL rewrite scheme would also make guessing harder.

Comment: In addition to both of you, if you're using `apache`, it's best practice to set `ServerTokens ProductOnly`

Comment: The `expose_php=off` will also hide the [Easter egg query strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458610/how-can-i-disable-phps-easter-egg-urls) (not sure if that's what you meant by quirks).

Comment: Note that these kind of settings probably won't affect persons that are able to e.g. fingerprint your server by analyzing the timing of responses. It might be pretty tricky to get around that kind of fingerprinting anyway. Maybe Rook can indicate if there is anything that can be done to make fingerprinting the server harder?

Comment: @owlstead "fingerprint your server by analyzing the timing of responses"; seriously? Does that work outside the laboratory environment? It seems a bit far fetched.

Comment: And hiding the tools used to build the site will not help with the 99.9999% of attacks which blindly fire exploits. Targeted attacks are not that common, and this is just security by obscurity.

Comment: @Matrix yes that will certainly work, and it is not far fetched at all

Comment: @owlstead Please provide me with some links as I'm unable to find any relevant information on this topic.

Comment: If you use APC you might need to change this variable: `apc.rfc1867_name`, if you use PHP Session upload check this variable: `session.upload_progress.name`

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve a little more of security through obscurity by also tweaking the following values:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
```

You can find some good advices here:

http://php.net/manual/en/security.hiding.php

Comment: Its not security though obscurity, its patching information disclosure vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Rook I understand your point but I still consider this kind of tweak something which is related to security through obscurity.

Comment: Just to clarify the precedent thouht:
I think that If something was bullet-proof, you wouldn't care to hide or spoof this type of informations.

Comment: if you ever hire a penetration tester there will most likely be a low finding for "Banner Information Disclosure".  Displaying version numbers is not required for the function of your application and is useful information to the attacker.  This is a vulnerability because it negatively affects security.

Comment: I agree but this kind of preventive approach will only makes things harder for an attacker: if you use a vulnerable PHP version, hiding error messages and version number doesn't protect you from someone who tries to exploit the known vulnerability by trial (from which the definition of [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)).

Comment: If anything, you might want to continue to advertise your versions, so a) you remain highly aware of keeping tight version control in your infrastructure and b) maybe some nice white hat will alert you if you are vuln to some 0day attack. :-)